# Assigning array values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, can I assign values to an array like the following?

```
a = 2, b = 3, d = 5, f = 6; //- these are the initial values

[a,b,d,f] = [f,b,a,d]; //- can I do this or will this error out?
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess ES6 has something like this. Is it related to ES6?

Comment: I'm sure entirely clear on what you're hoping to achieve from this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. [ES6 destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) allows you to do this.

```js
let a = 2, b = 3, d = 5, f = 6; //- these are the initial values

console.log({a, b, d, f});

[a, b, d, f] = [f, b, a, d];

console.log({a, b, d, f});
```

ES6, or [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) 6, is the current standard for JavaScript that modern browsers are expected to comply to. Not all fully comply though, so if you want to do something like this in production code, you should transpile your code with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) in order to make it compatible with older versions of Internet Explorer, and other browsers that still don't support ES6.